# How can i copy column table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table CLIENT

```
CLIENT_ID   NAME      CP       VILLE
1           razer     49004    St hallo
2           mayui     49005    Kubol
```

and another table AGENCE

```
CLIENT_ID  AGENCE_ID  ADDR   CP      VILLE     
1           1          qsdf   null    null
2           2          qsdf   null    null
1           9          dqsf   5454    5254
1           5           fff   4587    6568
```

How can i fill the CP and VILLE of table AGENCE ?

Of course i can delete / truncate AGENCE and use SELECT INSERT. But i can not do that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? but why are you storing redudant (duplicated) information at all? You can always join the two tables if you need the `cp` and `ville` value when accessing the `agence` table.

Comment: Can you not just use a simple `UPDATE` query linking the `AGENCE` table to the `CLIENT` table on `CLIENT_ID`?

Comment: Even better, can you not just use a simple `JOIN` query linking the tables at the point you need the info? What if you copy the data and `mayui` moves to another village?

Comment: @MartinParkin could you give me a code snipped please ?

Comment: @user609511 There are already two answers that contain appropriate code snippets - no need for me to add a third :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one way to do what you *asked* would be the following:

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.CP = C.CP, A.VILLE = C.VILLE;
  FROM AGENCE A
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT C ON A.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
```

A better way to do what you *really* wanted, would be to drop the columns from the `AGENCE` table and just do the join whenever you need it

```
SELECT AGENCE.AGENCE_ID, AGENCE.CLIENT_ID, CLIENT.CP, CLIENT.VILLE
  FROM AGENCE
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON AGENCE.CLIENT_ID = CLIENT.CLIENT_ID;
```

Make sure you have a proper foreign key setup.

Why is `AGENCE_ID` not the first column in your example by the way? It looks like a primary key.

Comment: Why would the primary key column need to be the first columns?

Comment: It doesn't, but I've never seen it differently.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL it would be:

```
UPDATE a
 SET VILLE = c.VILLE, CP = c.CP
FROM CLIENT c
INNER JOIN AGENCE a ON c.CLIENT_ID=a.CLIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

i just update the answer of @compuchip

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.CP = C.CP, A.VILLE = C.VILLE;
  FROM AGENCE A
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT C ON 
 A.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
AND
 A.AGENCE_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: Err... `AGENCE_ID = CLIENT_ID`? Now you've really lost me. I hope you have any clue what you are doing :)